# Is it correct to have a dependency property value that depend on another property value in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class that contains 2 data:

```
public class Settings
{
    EnumType Mode;
    float Rate;
}
```

The value of the attribute `Rate` depends on the value of the attribute `Mode`. 
I use the CoerceValue function to update ensure that the Rate value is correct at all time.

The property are binded to the UI in read only mode (one way) because I want to do some additional process on write. 
So I created an event on my UI control to know when the Rate property changed.

In my window the UI is binded to a static variable `SelectedSettings`.

My problem is the following:

When I change the value of SelectedSettings (with another settings class), instead of loading the new settings in the UI, it does the following operations:

- Set the new `Mode` value in the UI
- The previous operation start the coerceValue process and modify the Rate value.
- The modifiation of the rate value trig the event.
- The trigged event write the new value of rate in the `SelectedSettings`.
- Set the new `Rate` value (that is now incorrect).

What did I do wrong ? is my utilisation of dependency properties and coerce system invalid ?

**Edit**:
Here more information about my actual state

I created a user control to display the two settings options

```
public partial class EncodingQualitySliderControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BitrateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Bitrate",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(EncodingQualitySliderControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(EncodingQualitySliderControl.OnBitrateValueChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(EncodingQualitySliderControl.CoerceBitrateValue)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EncodingModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "EncodingMode",
        typeof(EncodingMode),
        typeof(EncodingQualitySliderControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(EncodingQualitySliderControl.OnEncodingModeValueChanged)));

    public event EventHandler<double> BitrateValueChanged;

    public EncodingQualitySliderControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.CoerceValue(EncodingQualitySliderControl.BitrateProperty);

        Debug.Assert(this.slider != null);
        this.slider.ValueChanged += this.Slider_ValueChanged;
    }

    public EncodingMode EncodingMode
    {
        get
        {
            return (EncodingMode)this.GetValue(EncodingQualitySliderControl.EncodingModeProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetCurrentValue(EncodingQualitySliderControl.EncodingModeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public double Bitrate
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)this.GetValue(EncodingQualitySliderControl.BitrateProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetCurrentValue(EncodingQualitySliderControl.BitrateProperty, this.GetNearestTickValue(value));
        }
    }

    private static void OnBitrateValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        EncodingQualitySliderControl encodingQualitySliderControl = sender as EncodingQualitySliderControl;
        encodingQualitySliderControl.slider.Value = (double)eventArgs.NewValue;
    }

    private static object CoerceBitrateValue(DependencyObject sender, object basevalue)
    {
        EncodingQualitySliderControl encodingQualitySliderControl = sender as EncodingQualitySliderControl;
        return encodingQualitySliderControl.GetNearestTickValue((double)basevalue);
    }

    private static void OnEncodingModeValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        EncodingQualitySliderControl encodingQualitySliderControl = sender as EncodingQualitySliderControl;
        Slider sliderControl = encodingQualitySliderControl.slider;

        // ... Some code that change the user control depending on the new mode.

        encodingQualitySliderControl.CoerceValue(EncodingQualitySliderControl.BitrateProperty);

        // Send ValueChanged in case of bitrate value change from coerce value.          
        encodingQualitySliderControl.BitrateValueChanged?.Invoke(encodingQualitySliderControl, encodingQualitySliderControl.Bitrate);
    }

    private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        this.SetCurrentValue(EncodingQualitySliderControl.BitrateProperty, e.NewValue);

        // Only send the bitrate value changed event if the value change come from the slider.
        this.BitrateValueChanged?.Invoke(this, e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

Then I have a class with my settings data:

```
public class ConversionPreset : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private EncodingMode mode;
    private double bitrate;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public EncodingMode Mode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mode;
        }

        set
        {
            this.mode = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double Bitrate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bitrate;
        }

        set
        {
            this.bitrate= value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Then i have a data binding between my settings class and my user control.

```
<controls:EncodingQualitySliderControl x:Name="EncodingQualitySlider" BitrateValueChanged="EncodingQualitySlider_ValueChanged"
                    EncodingMode="{Binding SelectedPreset.Mode, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Bitrate="{Binding SelectedPreset.Bitrate, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And some code in the main window to apply the modifications

```
private void EncodingQualitySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, double bitrateValue)
    {
        this.SelectedPreset?.Bitrate = bitrateValue;
    }
```

**Edit 2**:

Here is a minimal project that reproduce my problem:
[Linked dependency property test project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4MvaWJ6rmxnbFdlNlRKa1dnc0U/view?usp=sharing)

The wanted behavior is: when I start the application I want to see the preset1 (bitrate 32). Then if I check the preset2, I want to see the a bitrate value of 225.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You must show a more code, show the view, how you set the datacontext etc. Also seems that you missunderstud the concept of dependency properties, in WPF a dependency property is for UI controls. What I think you mean is an `INotifyProperty` changed object, so if you want your object updates the view when properties changed, your view model must implement this interface.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post to add more informations about my problem.

Comment: It is unclear from your question what the actual expected behavior is. When you say _"value of the attribute Rate depends on the value of the attribute Mode"_, do you mean literally that the rate value everywhere should vary according to mode? Or that you want to present the value differently to the user, while keeping the underlying rate value the same? If the latter, then probably you don't want to coerce, but rather use `IMultiValueConverter` and `MultiBinding` to combine the inputs of mode and rate to the correct UI presentation.

Comment: If the former, then I really don't understand what you're trying to do. In either case, please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem, along with a precise, clear explanation of what that code does and how exactly that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I added a minimalist test project that reproduce my problem (Edit2).

Comment: The question is better now. I can't se the implementation of the method `this.OnPropertyChanged();` this method should be called with the name of the property that changes, in other words, you need to raise the event this the property name that change.

Comment: Thanks Raùl. I used the attribute [CallerMemberName] on the OnPropertyChanged argument to retrieve automaticaly the property name [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). So it works well on this part ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to make my project work, thanks to the sample project.

I did not totally understood the concept of dependency properties and tried to avoid it, using events fired by controls.

I just remove all the code that set the values of my settings from events and then put the property binding in the mode "TwoWay". I didn't do that in the first place because I didn't know how to set my settings directly from binding. To make it work, I used (like Peter Duniho said, Thanks!) value converters (IValueConverter).

Thank you all for your comments!